# RTMP TEST NODEJS

Tags: node.js, rtmp, red5, rtmpdump

Can we test an RTMP link and find out if it is valid? Like an HTTP request (and have a header) using NODEJS?

Comment: add some implemented or tried links!

Answer (score 0):

For example I want to have an answer: 
rtmp: //cp108478.live.edgefcs.net/live/arte_en_1_800

If this link exists or not